# Substitutes for PM4PY process mining library in Python

Tags: python, process-mining

I am facing some issues when trying to create a directly follows graph using PM4PY library.
For some reason the, if the datapoints are too far from each other, it ignores some of the outliers on contructing the graph.
I am not able to find any alternative process mining libraries to PM4PY. Does know of any process mining library, other than PM4PY, which I can use?

Answer (score 0):

There are some alternatives to PM4PY BUT most of them are frameworks with plugin supports. You can find more information about all available process mining libraries and frameworks here: http://processmining.org/software.html

PS: I also started just now working more on PM4PY.